# How to access own computer drive when using puTTY on a cluster

Tags: mount, ssh, putty, cluster

I am completely new to this (""coding"" and such), so this may be one of the most basic questions asked around here but couldn't find the answer anywhere and have been struggling for long enough. So please, don't hesitate to be as detailed as possible when replying.

So here's my issue:
I am working from a windows 10 computer, using puTTY to use a cluster within my department. I have data that I would like to analyse using the computational power of that cluster, but I don't even know how to open/provide the path name to my drive. My data are stored on an external hard drive D:.

I have tried commands such as cd /d, cd /mnt/d, /mnt/d etc. The kind of thing that would work in wsl, but here I just get "No such file or directory". When trying pwd I just get /home/username.

I assume that to the cluster, D:\ doesn't mean much so I believe I need to establish a connection between that cluster and my D:\ but have no clue on how to do this.

Also, due to obvious restrictions I am not sure I can use sudo whathever.

Thank you for any help! Also, if you have guides for beginners, happy to read that.

Comment: Unless you are running some kind of externally visible file sharing service on your local Windows machine, you don't - instead, use an SCP or SFTP client from Windows (such as WinSCP, filezilla, or PuTTY's own commandline `pscp`) to "push" the files from there to the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, welcome to AskUbuntu and to the wonderful world of Linux! This seems to be a multi-issue questions so let's break this down to bite size asks.

1. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IVquJh3DXUA) a helpful video on Linux terminal commands just to get you started. If you have any specific questions, please feel free to ask them!
2. PuTTY is a remote terminal client, which means that it is intended to allow you to remotely, and securely, send commands into the server that you are connected to. As such, it doesn't automatically share or mount drives on your PC with/to the server. For security reasons, this is a good thing.
3. So, you CAN transfer files over SSH(Which is the program/server that PuTTY is connecting to), but PuTTY has an odd way of doing it. You have to use [PSFTP](https://www.puttygen.com/psftp), which PuTTY ships with, or install WinSCP. [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is graphical and would probably be easier, but either WILL work for planting files on your cluster.

If I have misunderstood anything in your original post, you have further questions, or this answered your question, please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand you have plugged the external drive into your windows computer that you are using putty on. Doing that does not connect the drive to the server you are connecting to through putty. Putty only gives you command line access to the machine but does not help you mount a drive. You should probably be using something like WinSCP to transfer data to a folder on the server. You should probably be able to connect winscp to the server with the same credentials that you have used in putty. Hope that helps.